# Swift Retrieve HTML data from Webview

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to obtain the data within the header of a web page that is being displayed in a UIWebView.

How do I get the raw (unformatted) HTML string from the UIWebView?

Also, I'm using iOS 9.

My question is similar to [Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview) , but this post is from 6 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992367/2446155) on the question you linked:

```
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                     @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

would translate into Swift:

```
let html = yourWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.innerHTML")
```

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` returns a optional, so you'd probably want to later use an `if let` statement:

```
if let page = html {
    // Do stuff with the now unwrapped "page" string
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did get the HTML code using the translated swift code, but after I submitted a form in the web view, I tried to use the same code to get the HTML code. It still displays the same HTML code from the previous page. Do you know what the problem might be?

I also tried webView.reload(), but it still didn't change

Comment: As long as you waited until the page [completely loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15916853/2446155) before calling the function, and you are using the same web view, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4:

```
if let html = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML"){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot get the html when the page render finished, if you got html too early, the result will be empty.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
     print("pageDidFinished")
     if let html = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.outerHTML") {
             print("html=[\(html)]")
      }

}
```