# How to parse data from webView to use in code

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` in my project which does some operations, after clicking submit in`WKWebView` it displays JSON data in javaScript that I need to pars in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Retrieve HTML data from Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747752/swift-retrieve-html-data-from-webview)

Comment: @Kuldeep, did you check with OP if he is using `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get source code of your `UIWebView`page.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML") { innerHTML, error in
        print(innerHTML!)
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked with me ,,,,

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) { do{ let content = try String(contentsOf: webView.url!) if let data = content.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) { let obj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] } catch{ } }

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.1 examples:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("redirect didFinish")
        print(webView)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
                                   completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                                    print(html as Any)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML data in the form of string using this piece of code

**in Objective C**

```
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

**in Swift**

```
let yourWebView = UIWebView();
let html : String = yourWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML") ?? "";
```

You have to analyze, what you have received, and do later process accordingly.

In your case, you might get the full json in the string.

Comment: @Mortiz sure, updated with swift. hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

your JSON comes in body tag then use this code or change from web side to give JSON in body tag

```
if let html = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML"){

            let data = html.data(using: .utf8)!
            do {
                if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any>
                {
                    print(jsonArray) // use the json here
                } else {
                    print("bad json")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```