# UIWebView Charging complete

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate, webviewdidfinishload

Is there any way to know if all of the content of the `UIWebView` is loaded?

I'm loading the content as follows:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: currentArticle.articleURL) {
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}

webView.footerView = footerForWebView
```

I already see this question:

[UIWebView: when did a page really finish loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996028/uiwebview-when-did-a-page-really-finish-loading)

But the answer is not correct, I try this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if ([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"]) {
        NSLog(@"FINISH")
    }
}
```

But is printing FINISH more than one time.

Comment: i don't get the question...

Comment: You want to know at what point the webView finished loading the actual content? `charged` is a very wrong word in this context.

Comment: To find out when a UIWebView has finished loading use a [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951)

Comment: @luk2302 what is what is the right word to you?

Comment: "load", "loaded", "loading" - the view does not *charge*, it loads.